# How many solutions does $15\cos x = x$ have on $[0,5\pi]$?

Tags: roots, numerical-calculus

So I found that on $(1,2)$ and $(4,5)$ we have two roots by the Intermediate Value Theorem. Am I correct?

**Edit 1**: I miscalculated there can not be a root in $(4,5)$ when using the theorem.

And while from the graph there is indeed one root apparently but this question has options. It says that the number of roots are either $3$, $4$, $5$ or $6$.

**Edit 2**: So I messaged my teacher and they said that it was a typo, the interval is  indeed $[0,5\pi]$.

Comment: Graphically, it seems like there is only one root ($x\approx 1.472$). The next root is at $x\approx 5.056$.

Comment: How did you find your solutions?

Comment: intermediate value theorem

Answer (score 1):

There is only one root around $x=1.5$.

At the end of the interval, make a simple series expansion
$$15\cos (x) - x=(15 \cos (5)-5)- (1+15 \sin (5))(x-5)+O\left((x-5)^2\right)$$Ignoring the higher order terms
$$x \sim 5+\frac{5 (3 \cos (5)-1)}{1+15 \sin (5)}\approx 5.05567 \,\,\, >5$$

**Edit**

Taking into account the answer key, the problem is $$\Large[0,5\color{red}{\pi}]$$

Comment: yes it appears that on the given interval thers  only one root. but the options are greater than 2 roots. can you check my edit? @Claude Leibovici    and can you explain the expansion you used?

Comment: @reijisakamaki. See my edit.

Comment: Well thats logical and maybe my teacher mistyped :D so if we let the interval be what you suggested what method should I use to solve the question? graph drawing? @Claude Leibovici

Comment: you were right. it was a typo @Claude Leibovici